# Alignment with a symbol within \sqrt

Tags: align

In this MWE I get an error.
My aim is that the "6" is appearing directly beneath the "2".

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{1 & 2345}= \\
& 6
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There are a number of ways to achieve this. Do you have a specific goal in mind other than placing one number underneath another?

Comment: @Werner In principle it's only about placing numbers. My goal is typesetting an algorithm similar to divison. I specified my question now in a new case called "Alignment and phantom". (I know about the package xlop but think this does not help here).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use alignment points (`&`) inside an `\sqrt` structure.  Instead, here I use `\phantom` to provide the requested buffer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{1  2345}= \\
 6\phantom{345 =}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want the rows closer together, use something like `\\[-6pt]` as the row separator.